# jest test emitting events for eventemitter objects (http)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

assume the following nodejs code

```js
const server = http.listen(8080,'127.0.0.1')
  .on("error", err => {
    // ...
  })

module.exports = server;
```

how to write a test using jest to emit the http "error" event (to cover the error event handler)?

Comment: Mock the server?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: do you have any minimal working example?

Comment: Isn't that your job ;) - I'm only commenting to help think of a solution. Not provide one. I found an example on how to test endpoints using jest https://zellwk.com/blog/endpoint-testing/

Comment: @evolutionxbox: thank you for your help. will wait for more elaborative comment\answer.

Comment: The updated article link actually helps a lot more. It uses _supertest_.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: visited that in the past, didn't help me as it does not cover my case (i am already using supertest). thank you again

Comment: See example of mocking an error: https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-tests-mocking-http-requests#toc-conclusion

Comment: @Mac_W: the error is for the `listen()` and not for a failed request\response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you create a server in module scope, the code will execute immediately when you `require` or `import` `server.js`. You need to stub the `http.createServer` before you require this module.

For testing `.on(error, callback)` method, you should use `mockImplementation` or `mockImplementationOnce`, so when the mocked server calls the mocked `.on('error', callback)`, you will get the original callback in your test case. Which means `handler` is equivalent to `callback`. When you call `handler(mError)`, the mocked error object will be passed into the original `callback`. Then you can use this `mError` test your code logic.

Here is the unit test solution:

`server.js`:

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();

server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1').on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

module.exports = server;
```

`server.test.js`:

```js
const http = require('http');

describe('60435647', () => {
  it('should handle error', () => {
    const mError = new Error('network');
    const mServer = {
      listen: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      on: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((event, handler) => {
        // handler is the original callback, the mError variable will be passed into the original callback.
        handler(mError);
      }),
    };
    const createServerSpy = jest.spyOn(http, 'createServer').mockImplementationOnce(() => mServer);
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    require('./server');
    expect(createServerSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mServer.listen).toBeCalledWith(8080, '127.0.0.1');
    expect(mServer.on).toBeCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mError);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60435647/server.test.js
  60435647
    ✓ should handle error (459ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
    Error: network
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60435647/server.test.js:5:20)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:100:37)
        at resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at promise.then (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 server.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.772s, estimated 6s
```

Comment: *thank you*. i am interested in doing the same for express app listen (that looks almost identical). can you share what should i take in mind or a reference to a snippet?

Comment: @Mr. Update the answer, please check.  There are two caveats to this scenario. This way is common way no matter what web framework you are using.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. now that i am able to test http.listen(), i seek to the same for express.listen(). would appreciate if you could [shed the light on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451082/jest-test-emitting-events-for-eventemitter-objects-express)