# jest test emitting events for eventemitter objects (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

trying to get an inspiration from [jest test emitting events for eventemitter objects (http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435647/jest-test-emitting-events-for-eventemitter-objects-http/60446830?noredirect=1#comment106936387_60446830) didn't solve my pain with [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express).

assume the following nodejs code

```js
// server.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(8080,'127.0.0.1')
  .on("error", err => {
    // ...
  });

module.exports = server;
```

how to write a test using jest to emit the http "error" event (to cover the error event handler)?

i tried:

```js
// server.test.js

it("should handle error", () => {
  jest.mock("express", () => () => ({
    listen: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    on: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((event, handler) => {
      handler(new Error("network"));
    })
  }))
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  const appListenSpy = jest.spyOn(app, "listen")
  require("./server");
  expect(appListenSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(app.listen).toBeCalledWith(8080,'127.0.0.1');
  expect(app.on).toBeCalledWith("error", expect.any(Function));
});
```

but what i get when running the test

```sh
 ● server › should handle listen error

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

    > 29 |     expect(appListenSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: Using `jest.mock` in each test case the functional scope is possible, but you should import/require the module after calling `jest.mock()`.

<del>You can't use `jest.mock` in the function scope.</del> It should be used in the module scope. Instead of using `jest.mock` inside the test case function, you should use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options)

E.g.
`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1').on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

module.exports = server;
```

`server.test.js`:

```js
describe('60451082', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mError = new Error('network');
    const appMock = {
      listen: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      on: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((event, handler) => {
        handler(mError);
      }),
    };
    jest.doMock('express', () => jest.fn(() => appMock));
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const express = require('express');
    require('./server');
    expect(express).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(appMock.listen).toBeCalledWith(8080, '127.0.0.1');
    expect(appMock.on).toBeCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mError);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/60451082/server.test.js
  60451082
    ✓ should pass (19ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
    Error: network
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60451082/server.test.js:3:20)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:100:37)
        at resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at promise.then (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 server.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.444s, estimated 10s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60451082

Comment: thank you so much for you assistance. when i run test, it fails on `expect(express).toBeCalledTimes(1);` due to `Received number of calls: 0`. i am trying to figure out why.

Comment: can you please make comment on how can you make the mocked `appMock.on()` return this, so other chained `on()` calls will work?

Comment: the mocks break other tests, so i tried placing `afterEach(() => { jest.clearAllMocks(); jest.resetAllMocks(); }` but it does not help. can you please give me a lead?

Comment: created a follow up question in a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456165/jest-clear-reset-all-mocks-so-other-tests-wont-be-affected)

Comment: I'm extremely sorry to help-vampire you like this, but this is the closest question I've found to [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69334442/1075247) (although not exactly)  I can't see how to apply the lessons in your answer to my situation? Maybe there's no relation, but I would still like to aks for your help if you're able to