# jest clear\reset all mocks so other tests wont be affected

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

the solution presented in [jest test emitting events for eventemitter objects (express)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60452334/1184717) solved a specific test case i have, though it seems to break others because of the mocks.

within the solution (linked above), there are calles to `require()`, so i suspect modules are cached with their mocks.

i have tried to clear the mocks by placing

```js
AfterEach(() => { 
  jest.clearAllMocks(); 
  jest.resetAllMocks(); 
  jest.resetModules(); 
}
```

but it seems it neither clear, no reset the mocks since other tests are failing.

how it the mocks should be cleared\reseted so other tests will act normal and pass before having the solution in the tests suite.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want to also ask this over on https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues (after searching there, first)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the way mocking is done. It's better to mock methods with `jest.spyOn()` instead of `jest.fn()`. With the second approach `jest.restoreAllMocks()` will not clear the mock

[More description here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrestoreallmocks)